# Invariant subspace and projection

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $F$ be a subspace of a Hilber space $H$, invariant under a bounded linear map $T$, and let $P$ be an orthogonal projection such that $Im(P)=F$.

> I need to show that $F$ and $F^\perp$ are invariant under $T$ if and only if
>   $PT=TP$.

For any $x \in F$, by definition, $T(P(x))=T(x)$, so that $PT=TP$ reduces to $PT=T$, which clearly holds if and only if $F$ is invariant.

But for $x \in F^\perp$ I'm completely lost. Obviously $P(T(x))\subset F$ and $T(P(x))\subset F$, but that doesn't depend on $F^\perp$.

Any hint or correction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $F^\perp = \ker P$ because $P$ is an orthogonal projection and $F = {\rm im} P$.

If $PT = TP$, then we have $T(F) = T(P(H)) = P(T(H)) \subseteq P(H) = F$ so $F$ is $T$-invariant. Similarly, $P(T(F^\perp)) = T(P(F^\perp)) = T(P(\ker P)) = 0$, hence $T(F^\perp) \subseteq \ker P = F^\perp$ and $F^\perp$ is $T$-invariant.

Conversely, if $F$ and $F^\perp$ are $T$-invariant, then we have $P(T(x)) = T(x) = T(P(x))$ for each $x\in F = {\rm im}P$ and $P(T(y)) = 0 = T(P(y))$ for each $y\in F^\perp = \ker P$. Because of $H = F\oplus F^\perp$ we conclude $PT = TP$ on all of $H$.